# AlertDialog inside onClickListener

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to start an AlertDialog from an onClickListener but I'm getting the following error.

```
The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
        mRecordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder( this )
            .setTitle( "Cast Recording" )
            .setMessage( "Now recording your message" )
            .setPositiveButton( "Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d( "AlertDialog", "Positive" );
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton( "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d( "AlertDialog", "Negative" );
                }
            } )
            .show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Change this line

```
new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
```

to

```
new AlertDialog.Builder( YourActivity.this );
```

This is because the constructor needs a Context type & `OnclickListner is not a Context type` so you use the object of your Activity.

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

In `new AlertDialog.Builder( this )`, `this` is referring to the listener, not the outer class instance.